# DAO OpendataBase (DSN Dialog always opening)

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, dao

I have an SYSTEM DSN "DSNtestwebform" linked to a MySQL DB. By trying to open the database, the DSN File Dialog is always opening. I don't know how to pass the correct DSN Name, that there is no dialog prompted. 
Does anybody know the correct way ?

```
          Set wrkODBC = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
          Set myDb = wrkODBC.OpenDatabase("DSNtestwebform", dbDriverNoPrompt, False, connString) ' here the Dialog appears.
```

Thx - Tzwenni

Comment: add username and pass to the DSN, via the Control Panel IIRC

Comment: Both are already stored, that's why I am so confused. I just need to select DSN, nothing more.

Comment: where does the code live?  Access or Excel.  If Excel then why not use ADO?  If access then one can go thru the GUI and link external tables by following the GUI wizard.

Comment: I need a DAO.database object to pass it to an DLL. This DLL is a MySqlAdapter for MS ACCESS and needs DAO.DataBase. So my question is, why this dialog appears, not how to workaround ;) And I even could work with ADO in ACCESS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompiling solved the problem:

> c:\...\MSACCESS.EXE mypath\myDb.accdb /DECOMPILE